# Resize UITableView depending on the size of UITableViewCell which contains this table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have the following View structure:

[image: View structure]

This view contains a main table with cells. Every cell of main table contains a label 'Point' at the top and a small subtable. When user clicks on the cell of main table, cell should expand to the bottom and the small subtable should take the free space.

I'm changing the size of main table cell using a flag in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method e.g.:

```
if (selected ...) {
  return 100;
}
return 30;
```

This works fine. The problem is in resizing subtable. I tried to use margin constraints (bottom one from the cell content view and top one from the Point label), but in this case table does not appear at all :)

Comment: The constraints you say you added should have worked. Do you see the table at all before you do the expansion? Do you also have horizontal constraints to the two sides of the cell?

Comment: I added two horizontal constraints and it worked :) Thank you :)